# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: java

I just started experimenting with java today (have experience with javascript and PHP) and am having trouble compiling this code.

I am using NewBeans IDE 6.8 on Mac.

It just says "One or more projects were compiled with errors."

The problem began when I tried adding a custom function in.

Here's the code (ignore all the comments):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class simpleServer
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }

    public void clientLoop()
    {
        // Message terminator
        char EOF = (char)0x00;

        try
        {
            // create a serverSocket connection on port 9999
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4041);

            System.out.println("Server started. Listening for connections...");
            // wait for incoming connections
            Socket incoming = s.accept();

            BufferedReader data_in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter data_out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream());

            data_out.println("Connected to Shipz Server." + EOF);
            data_out.flush();

            boolean quit = false;


            while (!quit)
            {
                String msg = data_in.readLine();

                if (msg == null) quit = true;

                if (!msg.trim().equals("EXIT"))
                {
                    if(msg.trim().equals("hShipzClient"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Client Connected");
                    }

                    if(msg.trim().equals("c")){
                        System.out.println("Player collision");
                        data_out.println("You crashed!");
                    }
                    data_out.flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection lost");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and be the first one to ask "have you looked at your compilation errors?"

Comment: Are you sure it nowhere sais which errors were found?

Comment: Generally Netbeans (and eclipse and intellij and... you get the point) will highlight/underscore where exactly it believes the problem is (unless you have manually gone and disabled this feature).  Can you tell us where the IDE thinks the problem is so that I don't have to copy / paste that code into mine?

Comment: -1: Didn't find the actual compilation error messages.  This sounds like a basic IDE question, not a Java code question.

Comment: Error messages are not for decoration. They tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, if the cause is understood, the solution is obvious. If you can't interpret error messages yourself, you should not omit them and let us guess the error based on the posted code monster. So, in the future questions, please include the error messages as well :)

Comment: Please format the code properly the next time and remove comments which are not relevant - fixed a bit.

Comment: Guys, lay off the poor kid.  If he's coming from PHP and Javascript he's not used to getting Compilation errors or using IDEs.  He doesn't know where to look for them!

Comment: Fair to ask the question but it would be heroic to delete it now that the issue has been found. i.e. what value does this now have to the community?

Comment: @Michael Easter: It might help to have a question that amounts to "I don't get my IDE" so we can close other questions and refer to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are missing an ending curly-brace "}" at the very end of your program.

Answer (score 3):

1) The code that you pasted is missing a closing brace.
2) once you uncomment the lines in your main method, you'll notice that you can't call the instance method clientLoop() from a static method i./e. main().
2.1) You need to create an instance of your class and then call clientLoop() against the instance.
2.2) But before your do that, we usually name our classes with a Capital letter in java, see http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html
2.3) Also you should try to align your braces for readability.
3) which should give you something like this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    SimpleServer ss = new SimpleServer();
    while (true) {

       ss.clientLoop();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles fine.  As mentioned, a final curly brace is missing from what you posted here.  Also, it is conventional to name classes in camel-case with the first letter upper-cased.